# Fetching an array data saved in Postgres using a function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a data saved as an array in a postgres database. I have successfully inserted it using a function. What I would want to do is to retrieve that data. Whenever I use select command, it returns successfully, but whenever I use the function below, I get an error. How do I retrieve the array data successfully?

```
create table userschedule(
  id serial unique,
  username text,
  monday text[],
  tuesday text[],
  wednesday text[],
  thursday text[],
  friday text[]
)
```

That is my table and below is the function that I use in attempting to get the data from the table.

```
create or replace function getschedule(par_username text) RETURNS table(monday text, mtuesday text, mwednesday text, mthursday text, mfriday text) as $$
    declare
        schedule TEXT[];
    begin
         schedule := ARRAY[]::text[];
         RETURN QUERY
             select mmonday
             from userschedule
             where username = par_username;
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: which error do you get? how does your sql command look like? please provide also a test data set.

Comment: maybe `SELECT * FROM getschedule('xyz')` would do? Honestly, I don't even see the need of `plpgsql`.. a simple `sql` statement would suffice.

Comment: What is the error you get? (Please **[edit]** your question, do not post additional information as comments)

Comment: Your function is defined to return rows with 5 columns, your query however only returns a single column. Additionally your result table returns scalar values for the columns (`text`)  but the columns in the table are defined as `text[]` so even if you select all columns the function signature and the result wouldn't match. What exactly do you want the function to return? The first element of each array? One row for each array element in each column? What exactly are you storing in those arrays?

Comment: You can use PostgreSQL `UNNEST()` function to convert a array type into record(s).. `SELECT username, UNNEST(monday) AS monday FROM userschedule WHERE username = 'username'` Should work just fine.

Comment: typo: `select mmonday` instead of `select monday` ?